# Exception encountered: #<RuntimeError: Application has been already initialized.> backtrace:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am working my way through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial.  In chapter 5, I've hit another bump in the road that I can't figure out nor find a solution for.

For one, my home page has dissapeared and I don't know why.  That is, for some reason the access to it is gone.

And when I run the test.  I get the following response:

**Exception encountered: RuntimeError:  Application has been already initialized.
backtrace:**

Can someone help?

---

Here is the backtrace (with some helpful formatting for easier viewing):

```
/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:135:in `initialize!'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'

/Users/tomgalpin/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

/Users/tomgalpin/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:11:in `block in run'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform_without_block'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1508:in `perform'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1586:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `loop'

/Users/tomgalpin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `block in main_loop'
```

Comment: Can you post the backtrace output in your question? that might give a clue it what might be causing the error?

Comment: Will do.  Just added it.  Thanks.

Comment: This is what I'm running:  $ bundle exec rspec spec/

Comment: I see you are using Spork. Have you followed the doc for bootstrapping rspec with spork?

Answer (score 1):

This fixed the issue for me:

```
bundle exec spork --bootstrap
```